# Error: required variable, found:value

Tags: java

I am trying this code in java. Why this error is encountered not able to figure out.

g(i,s)=co[i][1] gives this error. Why ?

```
    static int g(int i,HashSet<Integer> s){
        if(s.isEmpty()) {
            g(i,s)=co[i][1];
        } 
        else for(int j=2;j<=n;j++) {
            d=co[i][j]+g(j,s);
            if(d<min)min=d;
        }
        g(i,s)=min;
        return g(i,s);
    }
```

Comment: What do you think that should do?

Comment: I am trying to implement travelling sales man problem.

Comment: What you do think the type of g(i, s) that you're trying to assign to is?

Comment: `g(i, s)` returns an `int`. You can't set that result to something else... it's not a variable.

Comment: The program is trying to assign a value to the result of a method, how is that supposed to work?

Comment: it is difficult to understand what you are trying to do. Could you precise what do you have in mind about `g(i,s)` ? The 2 first times seems to be replaced by `return ...` but the last one ?

Answer (score 1):

`g` is a method. `g(i,s)` calls that method and returns a value. `g(i,s)=min;` attempts to assign a value to a value. You can only assign a value to a variable. You could do `min=g(i,s)`, assuming `min` is of type `int`.

Answer (score 0):

```
g(i,s)=min;
```

You are trying to assign `min` to the value `g(i,s)`, but you can only assign values to a variable.